# Using nodeJS for streaming videos

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I am planning to write a nodeJS server for streaming videos, One of my critical requirement is 
to prevent video download( as much as possible ), something similar to safaribooksonline.com

I am planning to use amazon s3 for storage and nodeJS for streaming the videos to the client.

I want to know if nodeJS is the right tool for streaming videos( max size 100mb ) for an application expecting lot of users. If not then what are the alternatives ?

Let me know if any additional details are required.

Comment: But why not nginx, wowza or even AMS ?

Comment: wowza is paid, looking into nginx and AMS.

Comment: AMS (Adobe Media Server) is paid too, for free, you can use nginx or Red5.

Comment: You can also see [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/?nc2=h_ls)

Comment: Any thoughts on how good or bad node might be on handling video streams ?

Comment: I am in the video streaming domain for more than 5 years, so with all factors and problems in this domain I don't think that's a good idea to write your "server" in nodejs knowing that there is a lot of servers that can do the same job.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i am considering nginx at the moment, as Red5 has not had any release since 2012 and it is RTMP based, which would make the implementation flash dependent.

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms you can't prevent video download. If a rogue client wants to do it they they generally can - the video has to make it to the client for the client to be able to play it back.

What is most commonly done is to encrypt the video so the downloaded version is unplayable without the right decryption key. A DRM system will allow the client play the video, without being able to copy it (depending on how determined the user is - a high quality camera pointed at a high quality screen is hard to protect against (!). In these scenarios, other tracing technologies come in to play).

As others have mentioned in the comments, streaming servers are not simple - they have to handle a wide range or encoders, packaging formats, streaming formats etc to allow as much each as possible and will have quite complicated mechanisms to ensure speed and reduce file storage requirements.

It might be an idea to look at some open source streaming servers to get a feel for the area, for example:

- VideoLan (http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html)
- GStreamer (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org)

You can still use noedejs for the main web server component of your solution and just hand off the video streaming to the specialised streaming engines, if this meets your needs.